# Simulating a 3D sphere using CSS

Tags: css, 3d, css-animations, css-transforms, css-shapes

I've managed to simulate a 3D sphere using CSS [here](https://codepen.io/takenoteiamhere/full/gqdLab). However, as can be seen, I used 40 `faces` to create that sphere. I'm afraid that the rendering may be too much for the average PC and would like to reduce the amount of `faces` used. Note that I will be doing a lot of rotation on the sphere and I'll be using 8 of those spheres (albeit smaller in size) on one page.

Also, if you look carefully, some sides have protruding edges that can be seen when I'm rotating the sphere. This is undesirable.

To reiterate:

1. I want to use less amount of `faces` if it is indeed too much for
   the average PC to render as I will be rendering **eight** of those spheres in my project
2. I would like to 'smoothen' the protruding edges if it doesn't include the usage of more `faces`

Comment: Probably your best bet is to use webgl, with some library (three..js or similar)